# Shifting array elements at specified indexes

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, stdvector, indices

What is the most efficient algorithm to shift array elements at specified indices left and right by one position?

For example shift indices [1,3,5] of [a,b,c,d,e,f] to the left to get [b,a,d,c,f,e]

I don't want it to rotate if the new index is out of bounds, if that makes sense.

I am using C++ std::vector for array storage.

Comment: Do you mean to swap places with the previous entry?

Comment: have you thought just using `std::swap`?

Comment: Your indices are off by one.

Comment: oops, fixed, thank you.

Comment: @toastie Do you want to swap all elements taken 2 at a time, or only specific indices with the elements to their left?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm interpreting your question as to swap the two adjacent entries of an array based on index. If this is wrong, then please clarify your question with an example for which this is not correct.

```
void swapElements(const std::vector<int>& indexes, std::vector<int>& array){
    for(auto i : indexes){
        if (i < 1 || i >= array.size()){
            continue;
        }
        std::swap(array[i-1], array[i]):
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please fix your const usage?

Comment: And: i >= array.size()

Comment: Oops. I really should pay more attention.

Comment: Yep, that's it, thank you! I can figure out doing it the other direction from here.

Comment: One caveat here is that it seems indexes need to be sorted for this to work correctly.

Comment: To be honest, still unsure of exactly what it is that you want to do. And how you want this function to function. The swaps are applied in the order they are specified. Which is what I assumed you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way is to use `std::swap` with the element with the given index and the element that preceds it.

For the first element you can use

```
std::swap( v.front(), v.back() );
```

Here is an example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<char> v = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' };

    for ( char c : v ) std::cout << c << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    for ( size_t i : { 1, 3, 5 } )
    {
        if ( i == 0 ) std::swap( v.front(), v.back() );
        else if ( i < v.size() ) std::swap( v[i], v[i-1] );
    }

    for ( char c : v ) std::cout << c << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
a b c d e f 
b a d c f e
```

If you do not want to rotate the vector then you can sibstitute the if statement for the following

```
for ( size_t i : { 1, 3, 5 } )
{
    if ( 0 < i && i < v.size() ) std::swap( v[i], v[i-1] );
}
```

Comment: He said he didn't want to swap if the previous would be out of range, so wouldn't it be a no-op for [0], not a swap with the back?